# How to have two different units on an axis in microsoft excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to create a graph that has my company's cash position all time, but go by month from the beginning up until the end of 2020. Then starting in 2021 I want it go be graphed by every day, every two days or even every week. Is this possible to have all in one graph? Or do I have to have two separate graphs?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, just have your date column represent a 1-month value through 2020, then have it switch to days for 2021. So, each month gets one row through 2020. Then each row is a day (or 2 days, or week) starting in 2021. As long as you don't want to show the full date on the x-axis, then this is fine.

Comment: I tried to do this but 2021 looks super bunched up, also the axis headings do not go by day. I created a separate table even that goes by months then switches to days in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are showing the amount of cash per unit of time, why not just use appropriate headings for the data, i.e. in 2020 Jan, Feb, Mar, etc., and in 2021 Week 1, Week 2, Week 3, etc. The curve will probably run lower in 2021, but the reader will see that these are weekly values. If you go for daily values, I'd make a separate graph, unless the cash amount has increased so much that the new daily values match the order monthly values.